# Cómo configurar Sap Business One usando gmail para enviar emails con contraseña de aplicación?

Tags: gmail, sap

Tengo un problema que le está sucediendo a muchas personas.
Desde el 30 de mayo de 2022, Google ya no brindará acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras.
El problema es que la confirmación de pedidos lo hacia con una cuenta gmail...
He probado de generar una contraseña especifica para la aplicación(SBO) desde ajustes de mi cuenta de correo. He realizado el cambio de contraseña en el service manager, reinicio el servicio, entro a SAP, hago la prueba de realizar una confirmación de un pedido, lo envío y el mensaje no sale a la "bandeja de salida" se queda en error.

¿Alguien podría decirme si generar una contraseña de aplicación sirve para Sap Business One?

Saludos.

[image: Imagen service manager]
[image: Bandeja de salida tras confirmar pedido]

Comment: Hola. No es evidente cuál es el error que se genera. ¿Hay algún tipo de log en el servicio SAP que puedas ver? Si es un error del lado de gmail, la respuesta suele ser bien explícita en lo que te falta hacer. Si es del lado de SAP, posiblemente también sea evidente. ¿Tienes 2FA activado en esa cuenta gmail?

Comment: Hola. He adjuntado dos capturas, una del service manager y otra de como compruebo que está fallando a la hora de confirmar pedidos, he buscado logs y no genera nada. No se bien bien por que falla ahora. Y si, tengo la 2FA activado por que para poder generar una contraseña de aplicación debo realizar el 2FA.

Comment: Tienes que usar tls

Comment: Podrías ser un poco mas explicito? :) Te refieres a la casilla de SAP "Use TLS Encryption" el por que no llego a entenderlo.

Comment: NO tengo ni idea de cómo funciona SAP, pero para conectarte al servidor SMTP, deberías usar la opción TLS. Más allá de eso, sin poder ver con algo más de detalle el fallo, es bien difícil adivinar

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, he solucionado el problema.

Comment: Súper! Podrías poner la solución como respuesta abajo (a menos que haya sido exactamente lo que te dije, en cuyo caso podría yo poner eso como respuesta jeje) :)

Comment: La solución es añadir 2FA en gmail y generar una contraseña de aplicación, insertamos la contraseña en el service manager y clicamos el checkbox de TLS